# что делает команда for i in {1..10}; do echo "(${RANDOM:0:3}) ${RANDOM:0:3}-${RANDOM:0:4}" >> phonelist.txt;

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование

for i in {1..10}; do echo "(${RANDOM:0:3}) ${RANDOM:0:3}-${RANDOM:0:4}" >> phonelist.txt; 
прошу разяснить всю команду по порядку что значит [for] [i] [{1..10}] и так далее. В общем дайте подробное описание команде что она и как делает и почему. Если кто может и знает конечно

Comment: генерирует случайные 10-значные телефонные номера, очевидно...

Comment: Извините, но что вы добиваетесь незначительными правками? Переоткрытия? Но ваши правки не проливают свет на главную причину, по которой вопрос был закрыт - **что не понятно** в приведённой командной строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дописывает десять строк вида (xxx) xxx-xxxx в файл phonelist.txt, где x - случайное число.

Comment: это я и сам знаю , но как она почему она именно так себя ведёт вот в сём мой вопрос